# Hardcoded data in SQLite table not showing properly (problem with number format - double)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, double

I hardcoded data to be put into a table (SQLite) in Android Studio and when I display the table onto a TableLayout, the doubles are formatted #.# instead of #.## (like I put them in).

Thank you in advance!

I even set the table to be REAL instead of TEXT when creating the table. How do I go about displaying the proper data (number format wise) onto my table layout, which also states is a double.

Comment: If you fetch the data in a Cursor by `getDouble()` then you must reformat them to `#.##` and store them as strings in an adapter before displaying them.

Comment: You can also custom format doubles as strings in sqlite itself with [printf()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#printf).